# Add elements to list in for loop - Nested loop

Tags: django, python-3.x

http://pastebin.com/zTMwBKUn

I'm having trouble creating a list that will be read by my django code. It's a python problem though, not django.

```
for line in reader:
    date =  datetime.datetime.strptime(line[0], '%m/%d/%Y').date()
```

Each row[0] has to be turned into a date object and despite the validation settings in the db model supposedly allowing it, I need to make all blank values be zero to get it to import.

```
    for entry in line:
        row = []
        entry = make_int(entry)
        row.append(entry)
```

This is the output:

```
['4/24/2016'] - This needs to be replaced with the 'date' vairable from pastebin
['A320']
['623NK']
['LAX-ORD']
['1']
['4.4']
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
['4.4']
['4.4']
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
```

The output needs to look like:

```
[date, A320, 623NK, LAX-ORD, etc... ]
```

So that it can be read by the following django code:

```
    # f = Flight(
    #   date = date,
    #   aircraft = row[1],
    #   aircraft_ident = row[2],
    #   route = row[3],
    #   legs = row[4],
    #   duration = row[5],
    #   landings_day = int(row[6]),
    #   landings_night = row[7],
    #   night = row[8],
    #   instrument = row[9], 
    #   approaches = row[10],
    #   cross_country = row[11], 
    #   second_in_command = row[12], 
    #   pilot_in_command = row[13], 
    #   simulated_instrument = row[14],
    #   instructor = row[15], 
    #   dual = row[16], 
    #   remarks = row[17], 
    #   simulator = row[18], 
    #   solo = row[19], 
    #   flight_cost = row[20],
    #   expenses = row[21],
    #   )

    # f.save()
```

Comment: Put your code in the question body, not in external link. And remember, it has to be a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Each time you are creating new array for each element as you have declared array inside inner for loop, array has to be initiated for each `line`, so it should be inside outer for loop but outside inner for loop.

```
for line in reader:
    row = []
    date =  datetime.datetime.strptime(line[0], '%m/%d/%Y').date()
    row.append(date)
    for entry in line[1:]:
        entry = make_int(entry)
        row.append(entry)
```